# Is it ok to get keywords and description from database?

Tags: php, jquery, database, seo

This isn't really a coding question, but I wanted to ask about what is more efficient and what should I use.

I am making a tutorials website, and each tutorial is brought up onto a page "blog.php" on which all data comes from the database. Now I have two ways I can fill in the meta keywords tag and meta description tag.

I was thinking of making 2 new columns in the blogs table, keywords, and description, and the meta tags would be filled up correspondingly from the database, and the database would get the keywords and description from user input (whover wrote the blog). I know how I would do this but is this efficient? Because I heard search engines have a harder time reading stuff from the database, so I wanted to make sure.

So I can use that OR do you recommend that I use JQuery to get text from the title tag and use that type of stuff? It would be really great because I was hoping to use PHP to make it dynamic, but if I should use Jquery and javascript then please tell which is better!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines **never read stuff** from the database.
They read only **HTML** generated by your script.

Storing keywords and description in database is all right.
The only thing you have to change in your setup is database design.
There shouldn't be keywords field in the blog table. Instead of that there should be `keywords` table and `keywords_blog` lookup table to link between keywords and tutorials.

Comment: thanks, I just read a tutorial about what you said too, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Search engines don't read from your database, only you do! What search engines have sometimes struggled with is dyanmic pages, i.e. a page like blog.php where the content changes via the query string, so blog.php?id=1 etc.

What many people do in this situation is use human readable URLs along with rewriting etc so your URLs might be
/blog/what-i-did-today
/blog/why-x-sucks
or similar. This would all be server by blog.php (or index.php or whatever) and then you can easily allow your bloggers to add their own keywords and descriptions via your database.

**But** do you really need to write your own? There is a ton of software out there that you can just download and install that does this already. Do you need to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: thanks for the last part of ur answer, and you see, the main point of making the website was to practive what ive learned, and I plan on teaching there and also making my own tools, plus the layout and everything of my blog/website is very unique :)